# Automated GUI testing of linux applications

Tags: linux, user-interface, testing

I'm looking for automated GUI testing apps.  So far, I've found Froglogic's [Squish](http://squish.froglogic.com), Dogtail, and the Linux Desktop Testing Project.

Are there any good free tools for testing linux apps out there?  I don't have the option of rewriting the applications that I'm testing.

Comment: I think pyautogui is a good choice.

Answer (score 7):

There are two different kind of tools that I know:

- Based on the accessibility layer: LDTP, dogtail, strongwind
- Based on image recognition: sikuli, xpresser

In my opinion, LDTP is the best tool right now since it provides a way to access programatically to the widgets in your application through the accessibility layer. However, the accessibility layer isn't really stable yet, in particular if it's enabled system-wide. So I'd let LDTP enable accessibility just for your application for testing.

Sikuli looks promising, but I'm reluctant to recommend it because I'm not completely sure that a change in resolution, theme, font, etc. won't break all your test cases and you may end up spending a considerable amount of time maintaining them.

Answer (score 1):

From my testing experience so far, I can definitely tell you that it is not a great idea to automate GUI and usability testing. It is better to leave these kind of testing for human beings.

Still if it is necessary to automate, I would recommend you to use good tools like Silktest or Selenium.